# SQL Query Not Exist

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables, Main and Payments. Main is a table of transactions, Payments is a table of which transactions pay for other transactions.

Main has many fields, like Invo, InvoDate, and Amount.

Payments is very simple; it just has PayInvo and DueInvo. [and a PK]

I have to figure out which what was still pending payment by the end of 2019.
My approach was as follows below.
[Main.Ac1 is the account. All accounts payable are between 2000 and 2999]

```
SELECT * FROM Main 
WHERE InvoDate BETWEEN #1/1/2019# AND #12/31/2019# 
AND Main.Ac1 BETWEEN 2000 AND 2999 
AND NOT EXISTS 
( 
SELECT * FROM 
Payments INNER JOIN Main ON Payments.PayInvo = Main.Invo 
WHERE Main.InvoDate BETWEEN #1/1/2019# AND #12/31/2019#
);
```

I expected it to ONLY return a list of transactions where the Main.Ac1 BETWEEN 2000 AND 2999 and also where a corresponding payment was NOT dated 2019, but it brings back nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the subquery in your `NOT EXISTS` clause is not correlated to your main query, so it always returns a result (as long as there are any rows in `Payments`) and so `NOT EXISTS` returns false and you get no rows from your query. You can correlate the subquery by not `JOIN`ing to `Main` but instead referring to the `Main` table from the outer query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Main 
WHERE InvoDate BETWEEN #1/1/2019# AND #12/31/2019# 
  AND Main.Ac1 BETWEEN 2000 AND 2999 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM Payments
    WHERE Payments.PayInvo = Main.Invo 
  )
```

Note you shouldn't need the date test in the subquery as it is covered by the outer query.

Comment: this worked, but I feel like it is worth mentioning that I have decided to add a "paydate" column to the payments table. longterm this seems like a good course

Comment: @NickFleetwood I think that's an excellent idea as you will frequently get payments that happen outside the period of invoice dates you are interested in. In that scenario you would add the constraint on the `paydate` column into the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Nick has provided a perfect explanation of the problem with your existing query. Just to offer an alternative, note that this can also be accomplished using an outer join with no subquery, e.g.

```
select main.* 
from 
    main left join payments on main.invo = payments.payinvo
where
    main.invodate between #1/1/2019# and #12/31/2019# and 
    main.ac1 between 2000 and 2999 and 
    payments.payinvo is null
```